# issue with inserting into Temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table `Profile` & `TokenState` table, that are joined by column called `TokenStateID smallint`. `TokenState` is basically an enum table, where each `TokenStateID` is assigned to some `TokenState char(2)`

To make it clear:

```
CREATE TABLE [AMS_APD].[TokenState] 
(
    [TokenStateID] SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    [TokenState]   VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
);
```

I want to join `Profile` & `TokenState` and store the result in temp table by `@ProfileTemp`

```
INSERT INTO @ProfileTemp(prof.[Eavtoken], ts.[TokenState]) 
    SELECT 
        prof.[Eavtoken],
        ts.[TokenState]
(SELECT *
 FROM [AMS_APD].[Profiles]
 WHERE  SDHASH1 = @SDHASH1) prof -- @SDHASH1 stored proc. parameter
 INNER JOIN [AMS_APD].[TokenState] ts
     ON prof.TokenStateID =  ts.TokenStateID
```

Problem is line `INSERT INTO @ProfileTemp(prof.[Eavtoken], ts.[TokenState])` is throwing an exception:

> Warning SQL71502: Procedure: [AMS_APO].[QueryProfileBySDHASH1] has an unresolved reference to object [@ProfileTemp].[TokenState].

Comment: What is your declaration for @ProfileTemp? Also, your insert into line should not reference the aliases of the tables being inserted into the variable as they specify the columns in the table variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the `()` should be the column names you're inserting into, not where you're taking the data from.

```
INSERT INTO
  @ProfileTemp([TokenStateID], [TokenState]) 
SELECT
  prof.[Eavtoken],
  ts.[TokenState]
FROM
  <etc, etc>
```

That assumes you already created a Table Variable with those column names.

If you want to have the table created for you, you can create Temp Tables *(slightly different from Table Variables)* like this...

```
SELECT
  prof.[Eavtoken]   AS TokenStateID,
  ts.[TokenState]   AS TokenState
INTO
  #ProfileTemp
FROM
  <etc, etc>
```

Comment: Second way, using `#ProfileTemp` cut down my code considerably ! Works great !